# ASP.Net MVC or HTML5 only client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui

I recently developed an application using HTML5 and KendoUI suite and I found it much quicker to develop than using MVC or ASP.Net.

Since HTML5 is getting so much support from vendors and with tools and platforms like PhoneGap and Windows 8 apps I was wondering what arguments will be made to rather choose MVC over a HTML5 client?

I am just trying to get some constructive motivations for and against going HTML5 client only and not making use of ASP.Net MVC or any other Server side technology to generate client HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hugely complex things you would never be able to do without some type of server side data processing, unless your app is just trivial.  Given the choice I would never go back to ASP.Net, but MVC4, Razor, EF5, Kendo and HTML5 are like greased lightning.  You have the choice of emphasis on a case-by-case basis to choose where it is most appropriate to solve a particular problem in this ecosystem.  You can still lean very client-side if you wish.  Properly architected things have their place though and I find the MVC model gives me almost any flexibility I need.  I don’t really consider MVC to be generating my HTML client code per say, but to be a facilitator, which makes me curious if your prior MVC projects may have tainted you with too much server-side reliance.  But ultimately we should be crafting the solution from the problem, not trying to solve every problem with the same solution, so your query could be completely on the money. (I believe I have said nothing.)